# GROUP BY and ORDER BY on different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by

I want to execute a query on POSTGRESQL server whose structure is as below:

```
SELECT col1, SUM(col2) GROUP BY col1 ORDER BY colNotInSelect;
```

I have tried to include the *colNotInSelect* in the GROUP BY clause but since it is a column with a distinct value, it defeats the purpose of using GROUP BY in the first place.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since it's distinct, *which* value of colNotInSelect do you want?

Comment: I don't want any value of colNotInSelect. I just want to use it in ordering the records returned by the query.

Comment: which one do you want to use in the ordering?

Comment: I want to group by col1 but order by colNotInSelect

Comment: You're really missing the point here. What would you do if you had (col1|col2|colNotInSelect): A|0|1, B|0|2, A|0|3, C|0|4, B|0|5? Which order would they come out? A then B then C? A then C then B? Something else?

Comment: So which of the potential multiple values for the column colNotInSelect for each distinct col1 would you like to order by? Why does your result have to be ordered?

Comment: colNotInSelect can have many different values in same col1 data. so order by colNotInSelect is impossible. if you apply some aggregate functioni to colNotInSelect, you can use it for ordering.

Comment: As suggested by @DavidAldridge, I used MIN() function that gave me the result I was looking for. Value in colNotInSelect is only used for ordering the rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot order by that column because it potentially has many values for each value of col1.

However you can apply an aggregate function to the column, and order by that.

for example:

```
SELECT   col1, 
         SUM(col2)
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY MIN(colNotInSelect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You question actually makes no sense because rows are grouped by col1 so there is no colNotInSelect in the grouped rows. Try to aggregate colNotInSelect before ordering, for example:

```
SELECT col1, SUM(col2), AVG(colNotInSelect) as col3 GROUP BY col1 ORDER BY col3;
```

If it isn't fit your need, maybe you should clarify what you're doing.